# How to get individual profile picture url from linkedin using rest api?

Tags: javascript, php, api, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I want to get public profile picture URL, but I am unable to get the authorization for public profiles, is it possible to get public profile picture URL in LinkedIn? Please help me out.

```
<?php
include_once '../lib/Splash/LinkedIn/Client.php';
session_name('linkedin');
session_start();
$redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
$api_key    = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$api_secret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$client = new \Splash\LinkedIn\Client($api_key, $api_secret);
if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
   unset($_SESSION['creds']);
   echo "<h1>Reset Session</h1>";
} elseif (isset($_GET['error'])) {
   echo "<h1>ERROR</h1> <p>{$_GET['error_description']}</p>";
} elseif (isset($_GET['code']) && !isset($_SESSION['creds'])) {
   $access_token = $client->fetchAccessToken($_GET['code'], $redirect_uri);
   $_SESSION['creds'] = $access_token;
} elseif (!isset($_SESSION['creds'])) {
   $url = $client->getAuthorizationUrl($redirect_uri);
   echo "Redirect to... <a href='$url'>$url</a>";
}
if (isset($_SESSION['creds'])) {
   $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['creds']['access_token']);
   $response = $client->fetch('/v1/people/~:(firstName,lastName)');
   echo "<pre>";
   var_export($response);
   echo "</pre>";
}
?>
```